# XSLT code to select string between first underscore until third underscore(will be cut after 10 digits)

Tags: xslt

current Output

```
<wd:GradeCode>CH_Service_Fly_test worker</wd:GradeCode>
<wd:GradeCode>CN_Dips_12 Engineer depart</wd:GradeCode>
```

Output needed

```
<wd:GradeCode>Service_Fl</wd:GradeCode>
<wd:GradeCode>Dips_12 En</wd:GradeCode>
```

Comment: Can you say whether you can use XSLT 2.0 or above, or are you limited to XSLT 1.0? Also, if you have any XSLT you have tried already, you should edit your question to show that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately little input. Which could probably work, would be the following function (depending on what you have in mind):

```
<!-- build a string after the first underline -->
<xsl:variable name="firstString">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., '_')"/>
</xsl:variable>

<!-- limit the firstString to 10 digits -->
<xsl:value-of select="substring($firstString/text(),1,10)"/>
```

The pending to use for each item.